# Will WSO2 Identity Server support Java 5( JDK 1.5)?

Tags: java, jar, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I wanted to implement Wso2 authentication and authorization on an old existing java web application in jdk 1.5 and running in oc4j.

Is wso2 identity jars are available in the version 1.5?
We are using IS 5.3 (Latest Version).How can I achieve this in an old application

Answer (score 0):

No, IS 5.3.0 supports only Java 1.7+.

It's very strange to hear such a requirement in 2017. Even Oracle doesn't support Java 1.5 now.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response.There are few applications which run in oc4j and jdk1.5.Here my requirement is SAML authentication implementation on this application and entitlement policy implementation.

Comment: Then the ideal solution would be run the Identity Server on a separate box with Java 1.7+ and use the exposes REST and SOAP services for SAML Authentication and Entitlement requirements